# send POST request to Itunes API via Postman

Tags: python, post, https, postman, itunes

For the Itunes Reporter API, I have an **access_token** and **vendor_number**.

https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/apd68da36164

I found some old Python code that was used to send API requests to this API:

```
    def _make_request(self,
                      cmd_type: str,
                      command: str,
                      credentials: Dict[str, str],
                      extra_params: Dict[str, str] = None
                      ) -> requests.Response:
        if not extra_params:
            extra_params = {}

        # command does not differ anymore, no matter if the apple id has multiple accoutns or not. a= is an invalid parameter by now.
        command = f'[p=Reporter.properties, {cmd_type.capitalize()}.{command}]'

        endpoint = ('https://reportingitc-reporter.apple.com'
                    f'/reportservice/{cmd_type}/v1')

        # account needs to be passed as data, not as parameter
        if self.account:

            data = {
                'version': self.version,
                'mode': self.mode,
                **credentials,
                'queryInput': command,
                'account': self.account
            }
        else:
            data = {
                'version': self.version,
                'mode': self.mode,
                **credentials,
                'queryInput': command
            }

        data = self._format_data(data)
        data.update(extra_params)

        response = requests.post(endpoint, data=data)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response


    def download_sales_report(self,
                              vendor: str,
                              report_type: str,
                              date_type: str,
                              date: str,
                              report_subtype: str = '',
                              report_version: str = '') -> Data:
        """Downloads sales report, puts the TSV file into a Python list
        Information on the parameters can be found in the iTunes Reporter
        documentation:
        https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/itcbd9ed14ac
        :param vendor:
        :param report_type:
        :param date_type:
        :param date:
        :param report_subtype:
        :param report_version:
        :return:
        """
        credentials = {
            'accesstoken': self.access_token
        }
        command = (f'getReport, {vendor},{report_type},{report_subtype},'
                   f'{date_type},{date},{report_version}')

        ordered_dict_sales_report = self._process_gzip(self._make_request('sales', command,
                                                     credentials))
        return ordered_dict_sales_report
```

Now, I want to replicate this in Postman but I am **not sure where to place the parameters from the "command" i.e vendor, reportType** etc. Do I pass them as a raw json in the body? Or as query paramas?

The endpoint I am using currently for a POST request is this:

https://reportingitc-reporter.apple.com/reportservice/sales/v1

I am passing a "BearerToken" as the authorization and this as the Body:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "mode": "Test",
    "queryInput": "[p=Reporter.properties, Sales.getReport, 85040615, sales, Summary, Daily, 20230101]"
}
```

but i get 400 Bad request error

According to the documentation, this is the Java syntax that i need to convert to Python:

```
Syntax
$ java -jar Reporter.jar p=[properties file] Sales.getReport [vendor number], [report type], [report subtype], [date type], [date], [version]* (if applicable)
```